# Pointers create constant string literals, why?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I was going through some documentation which states that

**First Case**

```
char * p_var="Sack";
```

will create a constant string literal.

And hence code like

```
  p_var[1]="u";
```

will fail because of that property.

<strike>**Second Case**</strike>

Also mentioned is that this is possible only for character literals and not for other data types through pointers. So code like

```
float *p="3.14";
```

will fail, resulting in a compiler error.

But when i try it out i don't get compiler errors ,accessing it though gives me `0.000000f`(using gcc on Ubuntu).

So regarding the above, i have three queries:

1. Why are string literals created in **First Case** read-only?
2. Why are only string literals allowed to be created and not other constants like float through pointers?

<strike>3. Why is **Second Case** not giving me compiler errors?</strike>

**Update**

Please discard the 3rd question and second case. I tested it by adding quotes.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premise is wrong: pointers don’t create any string literals, neither read-only nor writeable.

What *does* create a read-only string literal is the literal itself: `"foo"` is a read-only string literal. And if you assign it to a pointer, then that pointer points to a read-only memory location.

With that, let’s turn to your questions:

> Why are string literals created in First Case read-only?

The real question is: why not? In most cases, you won’t want to change the value of a string literal later on so the default assumption makes sense. Furthermore, you *can* create writeable strings in C via other means.

> Why are only string literals allowed to be created and not other constants like float?

Again, wrong assumption. You *can* create other constants:

```
float f = 1.23f;
```

Here, the `1.23f` literal is read-only. You can also assign it to a constant variable:

```
const float f = 1.23f;
```

> Why is Second Case not giving me compiler errors?

Because the compiler cannot check in general whether your pointer points to read-only memory or to writeable memory. Consider this:

```
char* p = "Hello";
char str[] = "world"; // `str` is a writeable string!

p = &str[0];

p[1] = 'x';
```

Here, `p[1] = 'x'` is entirely legal – if we hadn’t re-assigned `p` beforehand, it would have been illegal. Checking this cannot be generally done at compile-time.

Comment: I did not mean constants of other data types cannot be created, i meant constants of other data types cannot be created through pointers. Sorry if was being unclear

Comment: @DesertIce Fair enough. The answer to that is a bit complicated but the easy version is: because it’s utterly useless. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just wanted to know if there was compiler/optimization related answer to the first 2 questions

Comment: “constants of other data types cannot be created through pointers” They can in C99 with anonymous arrays. See http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~martin/resources/kung-f00.html

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question:

- Why are string literals created in **First Case** read-only?

`char *p_var="Sack";`

Well, the `p_var` is assigned with the starting address of the memory allocated to the string `"Sack"`. `p_var` content is not read-only, since you haven't put the `const` keyword anywhere in C constructs. Although manipulating the `p_var` contents like strcpy  or strcat may cause undefined behavior.

Quote C ISO 9899:

The declaration
`char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";`
defines *plain* char array objects `s` and `t` whose elements are initialized with character string literals.
This declaration is identical to:
`char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };`
The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration:
`char *p = "abc";`
defines `p` with type *pointer to char* and initializes it to point to an object with type *array of char* with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use `p` to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined.

An explanation of why it could be read-only per your platform and compiler:

Commonly string literals will be put in "read-only-data" section which gets mapped into the process space as read-only (which is why you seem to not being allowed to change it).

But some platforms do allow, the data segment to be writable.

- Why are only string literals allowed to be created and not other constants like float? and the third question.

To create a float constant you **should** use:
`const float f=1.5f;`

Now, when you are doing:
`float *p="3.14";`
you are basically assigning the string literal's address to a float pointer.

Try compiling with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`. You will find out what is happening.
It *works* because, in practice, there's no difference between a `char *` and a `float *`  under the hood.

Its as if you are writing this:
`float *p=(float*) "3.14";`

This is a well-defined behaviour, unless the memory alignment requirements of float and char differ, in which case it results in undefined behaviour (Reference: C99, 6.3.2.3 p7).

Answer (score 0):

1. Efficiency
2. they are
3. It's a string mind the quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
float *p="3.14";
```

This is also a **string literal** !

```
  Why are string literals created in First Case read-only?
```

No, both `"sack"` and `"3.14"` are string literals and both are read-only.

---

Why are only string literals allowed to be created and not other constants like float?

If you want to create a float const then do:

```
const float p=3.14;
```

---

```
Why is Second Case not giving me compiler errors?
```

You are making the pointer `p` point to a string literal. When you dereference `p`, it expects to read a float value. So there's nothing wrong as far as the compiler can see.

Comment: Sorry i was unclear in my question, i have updated it. Anyway I did not mean constants of other data types cannot be created, i meant constants of other data types cannot be created through pointers.